# How does Visual Assist X rename symbol work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, hungarian-notation, visual-assist

I want to remove the Hungarian Notation from a gigantic piece of code,but I'm not sure how the addon handles replaces.I mean - if I have:

```
void DoNothing(int *pNothing)
{
pNothing = 0;
};
```

And I click on 'pNothing' and rename it to 'nothing' wiht the VA refactor tool,will that only rename it only in this function or will it rename all pointers named pNothing in every function and class in the entire project?

Comment: VA will only rename it in that function scope. But why don't you just try it? VA also got a preview, so go on...

Answer (score 2):

> Rename changes the definition and all references, and declaration when
>   programming in C/C++, C# and VB. Rename optionally changes comments
>   and strings.

So in your example, it will only change the name in the function. But if you were to change a name of a class member, then it will change it in your entire solution.

Reference : http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/rename.asp